# approximation of random variable with conditional expectation

Tags: random-variables, conditional-probability

Let $\mathcal{F}_n$ be a filtration on probability space $(\Omega,\sigma)$, and assume the whole sigma algebra $\sigma$ is generated by all the $\mathcal{F}_n$. Does $\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{F}_n)$ converge pointwise to $X$? If not, can you give a simple example?

Is there any result on how well $E(X|\mathcal{G})$ approximates $X$, depending on how close $\mathcal{G}$ is to the whole sigma algebra $\sigma$?

Comment: It does converge a.s.  and in $L^{1}$ to $X$ by martinagle convergence theorem.

Comment: Do you mean Doob's convergence theorem? It only says the condition expectations converge pointwise to something, how does it converge to X?

Comment: It conveges to $E(X|F_{\infty})$ in general.

Comment: Oh I see, I was checking my book and it said to use Levy's upward theorem. Haven't got up to that part yet. Silly question that would be obvious if I learned more.